# His/Her name's with name and surname

Tags: phrase-usage, contractions

Can I use **his/her** **name's** with name and surname or only name?

For example:

> His name's Robert Lewandowski.
>
> Her name's Taylor Swift.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use it with any name or combination of names.  Here's an example from a real book: [Freg said, "His name's John Y. Lipman."](https://books.google.com/books?id=gVhXDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT17&dq=%22his+name%27s+john%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit98DLm4jSAhVFMyYKHR34BjgQ6AEIQzAI#v=onepage&q=%22his%20name's%20john%22&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is correct, you can do this.